# vim :s command with regex to select a second occurance of a character

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I want this block of text below :-

```
119, 'Youth Campus,Janakpur', Janakpur  
978, 'Yog Kumar Janta Campus, Balwa-3', Mahottari  
806, 'Yerawati Aadarsha Multiple Campus, Lalmatiya Deukhuri, Dang', Dang  
613, 'Yasok Campus, Yasok, Panchther', Panchthar  
458, 'Yagyodaya Dudhnath Tharu Multiple Campus,Suddhodhan-3,Ramawapur', Rupandehi  
1008, 'Yagnyabhumi Multiple Campus, Dharapani', Dhanusha  
546, 'Xavier International College, Kamalpokhari,kath', Kathmandu  
362, 'Xavier Academy Science College, Lazimpat, Kathmandu', Kathmandu
```

to change to :-

```
119, 'Youth Campus', Janakpur  
978, 'Yog Kumar Janta Campus', Mahottari  
806, 'Yerawati Aadarsha Multiple Campus', Dang  
613, 'Yasok Campus', Panchthar  
458, 'Yagyodaya Dudhnath Tharu Multiple Campus', Rupandehi  
1008, 'Yagnyabhumi Multiple Campus', Dhanusha  
546, 'Xavier International College', Kathmandu  
362, 'Xavier Academy Science College', Kathmandu
```

by using vim `:s` command. For that I need to *delete* the characters after the **second `,`** upto a **`'`** character to it's right. *How do I specify this condition using regex?*

The `:s/,.*',/,/g` deletes the entire text inside the `'`s. and `:%s/,.*'/','/g` also doesn't work as expected.

I need a substitute command that gets the result along with some explanation of how the regex works/functions!

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
:%s/\v^(\d+,\s*'[^',]*).*(',[^,]*)$/\1\2/g
```

See the [PCRE-equivalent demo of this regex](https://regex101.com/r/U5V76W/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of a string (line in Vim)
- `(\d+,\s*'[^',]*)` - Group 1: one or more digits, a comma, zero or more whitespaces, `'` and then zero or more chars other than `'` and `,`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `(',[^,]*)` - Group 2: `',` + zero or more chars other than `,` as many as possible
- `$` - end of a string (here, line).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this simple approach:

```
:%s/,[^']\+\ze',//g
```

With the help of `:set incsearch hlsearch`…

1. `,` matches a comma:

   [image: step 1]

   Hmm, too many matches… but that's expected.
2. `[^']\+` matches one or more characters that are not a straight quote:

   [image: step 2]

   Hmm, still too many matches…
3. `',` matches a straight quote followed by a comma:

   [image: step 3]

   We are getting there…
4. `\ze` is a bit hard to explain. Basically, you have a "real" match that corresponds to the full regexp and an "actual" match that leaves out whatever comes after `\ze`. Here, we use it to stop the actual match before the `',`:

   [image: step 4]

   Here we are.

FWIW, the two last slashes and the `g` are not necessary in this case since:

- there is no replacement,
- there is only one match per line.

Therefore, you can safely go with:

```
:%s/,[^']\+\ze',
```

Comment: `\ze` is basically the same as a lookahead, correct?

Comment: Kind of. But it only really works once in a pattern, even if used several times, while Vim's `:help \@=` and `:help \@!` are much closer to what you would have in perl.

Comment: So... more like an inverted `\K` then.

Comment: On minor remark, I believe the `,` character is called a *comma* while a *colon* looks like `:`

Comment: Now *coma* is a state of unconsciousness while *comma* ... okay, I'll stop being pedantic. Your answer is perfectly understandable the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use:

```
:%s/\(,.\{-}\),.\{-}'/\1'
```

`\(,.\{-}\)` part can be modify to match third and further occurrences, and so on and so forth